# how to read objects in php in loop

Tags: php

I started learning PHP and i stuck somewhere reading the multidimanation array below. Could any PHP expert provide me some info how i can read below object array in PHP

Thank you in advance.

```
[0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["section"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-4"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["section"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-5"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["section"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-2"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
Mona

Comment: That is a multi-dimensional array, not an `object`.

Comment: yes as i said i am learning php

Comment: have you heard about loops,,,ex foreach

Comment: print_r($name_of_object);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $array_name[0]["section"][0]["id"];
```

Echos `wid-id-1-1`.

You'll have to replace `array_name` with the name of your array to read this. You can use this like any other variable. Just make sure to use quotes when talking about a key that's a string (not a number).

You may also want to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Hi @annonomus thank you for reply i tried this but it did not worked.

Comment: @monamona whoops... forgot the second `[0]`. Let me know if that doesn't work and provide any error messages. Sorry about that!

Comment: Great Annonomus it worked... than you so much... how i can read it in loop